# Unable to setup localhost HTTPS server and open it in a browser

Tags: java, ssl, https, jsse

I tried to setup a http server configured with a keystore, and then access it in a browser. However, I fail to do so. I am using mac os 10.11.6 version.

a.) Command used to generate keystore: `keytool -genkey -alias vrkey -keyalg RSA`

b.) Commands used to export the cert : `keytool -export -alias vrkey -file vrtest.cer`

c.) Command used to get the cert added to truststore `: keytool -import -alias test -keystore $HOME/.truststore -file vrtest.cer`

Here are things I tried from my end :

1. Connect from terminal and I get proper response:

   ```
   Administrator-MacBook-Pro:src administrator$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/.truststore sample.MySecureClient localhost 8999

   Who is John

   what is he ?
   ```
2. Give an incorrect truststore and see if errors come in ssl, but still I am able to get response from the server :

   ```
   Administrator-MacBook-Pro:src administrator$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/.truststore123 sample.MySecureClient localhost 8999

   Who is John

   what is he ?
   ```
3. Tried to connect with open ssl and curl, but I don't think SSL context is set :

   ```
   Administrator-MacBook-Pro:src administrator$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8999
   CONNECTED(00000003)
   4425:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
   ```

openssl with debug option :

```
    Administrator-MacBook-Pro:src administrator$ openssl s_client -debug -connect 127.0.0.1:8999
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    write to 0x7fd43bc1b320 [0x7fd43c00d000] (130 bytes => 130 (0x82))
    0000 - 80 80 01 03 01 00 57 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   ......W... ..9..
    0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
    0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 00 00 9a 00 00 99 00   ..3..2../.......
    0030 - 00 96 03 00 80 00 00 05-00 00 04 01 00 80 00 00   ................
    0040 - 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06-00 40 00 00 14 00 00 11   .........@......
    0050 - 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00-80 00 00 03 02 00 80 00   ................
    0060 - 00 ff 75 85 ef 4c 18 89-5e 13 74 fd b3 25 3a a6   ..u..L..^.t..%:.
    0070 - e0 c7 b7 80 15 62 55 58-f5 1e 8e f1 f5 07 8f 8b   .....bUX........
    0080 - 23 91                                             #.
    read from 0x7fd43bc1b320 [0x7fd43c012600] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
    0000 - 77 68 61 74 20 69 73                              what is
    4434:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
```

Using curl command

```
    Administrator-MacBook-Pro:src administrator$ curl -v -k "https://127.0.0.1:8999"
    * Rebuilt URL to: https://127.0.0.1:8999/
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8999 (#0)
    * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:-9847
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:-9847
```

4. Set the system properties in the code for both client and the server and run the code from intelliJ IDE. I get the proper request / response output but I don't see that https server is set because I can't the server in the browser.
5. Open the https://localhost:8999/ url in chrome/safari, but unable to open it.
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now assuming my keystore and trust store are set properly. What am I doing wrong here ?

Following is the information :

CODE FOR SERVER

```
package sample;

import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MySecureServer extends Thread {

private Socket sock;

public MySecureServer(Socket s ) {
    this.sock = s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", File.separator + "Users"
            + File.separator + "administrator"
            + File.separator + ".keystore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "abcde");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
    ServerSocketFactory ssf = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(8999);
    while (true) {
        new MySecureServer(ss.accept()).start();
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        String data = br.readLine();
        pw.println("what is he ?");
        pw.close();
        sock.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

######CODE FOR CLIENT#####

```
package sample;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MySecureClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SocketFactory sf = SocketFactory.getDefault();
    //Socket s = sf.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    Socket s = sf.createSocket("localhost", 8999);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Who is John");
    pw.println("Who is John");
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    s.close();
}
}
```

**EDITED**

I wrote another secure client to get ssl context and got the error :

```
Hostname = null


Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificateChain(SSLSessionImpl.java:482)
    at sample.MyNewSecureClient.main(MyNewSecureClient.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Following is the secure client code :

```
package sample;

import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MyNewSecureClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    //SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("localhost", 8999);

    SSLSession sess = sslSocket.getSession();
    String host = sess.getPeerHost();
    System.out.println("Hostname = " + host);
    X509Certificate[] certificates = sess.getPeerCertificateChain();
    String dn = certificates[0].getSubjectDN().getName();
    System.out.println("Subject DN = " + dn);
    X500Name name = new X500Name(dn);
    if (!host.equals(name.getCommonName())) {
        System.out.println("Warning: Expected " + host + " and got " + name.getCommonName());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Who is John");
    pw.println("Who is John");
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    sslSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: (0) I fixed your formattting. (1) Your first client and server don't do SSL/TLS at all; they are communicating with other in clear. That's why `openssl s_client`, `curl`, and browsers, all of which ARE doing SSL/TLS, can't communicate with them. SSL/TLS client must use `SSLSocketFactory` note SSL (or else `URLConnection` on an `https:` URL which does SSLSocket for you) and server must use `SSLServerSocketFactory` note SSL. (2) Your second client does use `SSLSocketFactory` but tries to check `.getPeer*` which are only available after the handshake is completed (successfully) ...

Comment: ... and JSSE client does handshake only when you read or write on the data streams for the socket (implicit) or call `SSLSocket.startHandshake` or `HttpsURLConnection.connect` (explicit). (3) The cert for an HTTPS server may contain the hostname in SubjectAlternativeName extension rather than Subject CommonName attribute, since rfc2818 in 2000.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `HttpURLConnection.connect()` doesn't even create a TCP connection, let alone perform a TLS handshake. Otherwise all good points.

Comment: @EJP debug it and see. Concrete `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect()` calls `sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect()` which gets _either_ TCP or proxy from `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect()` and then calls `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect()` which does the `SSLSocket` object setup and handshake, including hostname verify.